# doWork is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2

We're upgrading to Hibernate 4.  We're getting a damned if you do/damned if you don't with regards to this settings:

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>
```

If we set it, we get:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: doWork is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
```

If we leave it out, we get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1010)
```

I should note that this code worked in hibernate 3 without the setting.  The code hasn't really changed.  In fact, we actually had it working for a while in hibernate 4 until a recent upgrade from DB2 9.5 to 10.5.  I'm not really sure how that would impact what seems like hibernate config problems, but that's the main change that seems relevant.

update - The doWork has not changed, but here it is:

```
        session.doWork(new Work() 
        {
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException 
            { 
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.setProperty(WSConnection.CLIENT_ID, uId);
                props.setProperty(WSConnection.CLIENT_APPLICATION_NAME, appName);

                if (connection instanceof WSConnection) {
                    WSConnection wconn = (WSConnection) connection;
                    wconn.setClientInformation(props);
                } else {
                    log.error("Connection was NOT an instance of WSConnection so client ID and app could not be set");
                }
            }
        }
```

update 2 - The Spring config gets long, but here's the bit that seems relevant to transactions and such.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="gov.usdoj.afms" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.provider">javassist</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">K702PRDR</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<!--Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="gov.usdoj.afms" />

<!--BEGIN Data sources - By convention data sources are prefixed with the
    schema name against which they operate. -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="${ds.jndi}" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="gov.usdoj.afms.cats.util.hibernate.AfmsHibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The custom txmanager just sets some connection attributes.  We've used it throughout hibernate 3, and it worked with 4 initially.

Update 3 - 
I will say we've "learned" that we think this might be a classloader deal.  When running in RAD 7, we've always had to put the jpa 2.1 in the ext folder to get it loaded.  In RAD 8.5, we planned to use a parent_last classloader (the ext trick doesn't work anymore).  But this seems to throw the above exceptions.

If we deploy from RAD 8.5 with the classloader setting, it works.  If we deploy from RAD 7 with ext folder trick, it works.  But neither trick works in the other version.  So we have workarounds, but they involve different setups in different workspaces, which is not ideal.

Comment: Ignore the DB2 version thing, we just pointed at a 9.5 database again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post an example of your `doWork` code that is no longer working? Do you create a transaction before calling `doWork`? If not, try to create one!

Comment: Could you post your Spring configuration as well?

Comment: Try to add `session.beginTransaction();` before and `session.getTransaction().commit();` after your `session.doWork()`.